# Salesforce Entry Event Campaign Does Not Pull in Contacts on Activation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign, campaign-member

When selecting a campaign from a salesforce data entry event in Journey Builder it states "Select campaigns to add members to the Journey. Only members added to these campaigns after activation will enter the Journey." <- So you need to activate the Journey Builder Campaign then Add the contacts in the CRM to that campaign in order for them to be evaluated and added?

I already had the contacts in the campaign in the crm and when I activated in Journey Builder nothing happened. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Activate your Journey first, then drop your Contacts/Lead within the Campaigns.

Comment: This was the solution that I came upon as well